# URL decoding with unfiltered

Tags: scala, unfiltered

I'm working with [Unfiltered](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Unfiltered.html) 0.6.8 (using the Jetty connector) and have encountered an odd behaviour: path segments aren't URL decoded.

The following bit of code is my minimal test case:

```
import unfiltered.request._
import unfiltered.response._

object Test extends App with unfiltered.filter.Plan {
  def intent = {

    case reg @ Path(Seg(test :: Nil)) =>
      println(test)
      ResponseString(test)
  }

  unfiltered.jetty.Http.local(8080).filter(Test).run()
}
```

Querying `http://localhost:8080/some_string` yields the expected result: `some_string`, both on the client and server side.

On the other hand, `http://localhost:8080/some%20string` yields `some%20string` on both client and server, rather than the `some string` I was expecting.

Working around the issue is trivial (`java.net.URLDecoder#decode(String, String)`), but I'd like to know if:

- I'm forgetting something trivial and making a fool of myself.
- unfiltered has a kit to deal with the hassle automatically.
- if none of the above, is there a particular reason for this behaviour, or should I file a bug report?

As a side note, the `unfiltered` tag doesn't exist and I do not have enough reputation to create it, which is why I defaulted to `scala`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strange, I'm seeing this behavior too.  There is nothing in the `Seg` object that does any sort of url decoding prior to splitting up the path segments and I don't see anything else in the framework for this either.  I ran into a post that detailed a solution using a custom extractor as follows:

```
object Decode {
  import java.net.URLDecoder
  import java.nio.charset.Charset

  trait Extract {
    def charset: Charset
    def unapply(raw: String) = 
      Try(URLDecoder.decode(raw, charset.name())).toOption
  }

  object utf8 extends Extract {
    val charset = Charset.forName("utf8")
  }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
case reg @ Path(Seg(Decode.utf8(test) :: Nil)) =>
  println(test)
  ResponseString(test)
```

Or like this if you wanted the entire path decoded:

```
case reg @ Path(Decode.utf8(Seg(test :: Nil))) =>
  println(test)
  ResponseString(test)
```

Thankfully the framework is flexible and open to extension like this, so you certainly have options.